# Issue with clearing onscreen visible numbers in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a calculator app using React JS. Even though the app is almost complete, I have one small bug. When the `clear` button is clicked, the numbers on screen becomes `0` but then after if any number key is pressed, the previous number reappears. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-panini-xwy1n) is the code snippet of my app. I guess the bug is present in `Display.js` file or `App.js` file.
How to fix this bug?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your codepen, you need to reset "value" inside of "NumberPad" component.

I've used a useEffect to check if "value" in app.js is set to 0, if so, it sets the "value" in "NumberPad" component as "0".

For your reference:

https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-wildflower-zt0rv?file=/src/Components/NumberPad.js

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, in `NumberPad.js`, the `handleNumberClick` function calls the `number` function with its own state.

Your `clear` button has no link to the state saved in the `NumberPad`

What you can do is [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to `App.js` so you have only one source of truth for the display to show